# Jquery UI droppable inside bootstrap columns

Tags: jquery-ui

using Jquery UI, I'm trying to drag elements and drop them inside bootstrap columns. A simple idea but doesn't work, as you may try yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/r4rp93ac/1/

It only drops inside the first bootstrap column

I found related questions:

[Bootstrap 3 column class interfering with jquery-ui droppable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042564/bootstrap-3-column-class-interfering-with-jquery-ui-droppable-div)

[jQuery UI Draggable with Bootstrap layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642553/jquery-ui-draggable-with-bootstrap-layout)

and tried to add

```
 .ui-draggable-handle {
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .ui-draggable-dragging {
     z-index: 10000!important
 }
```

to css, but doesn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately while stripping down the problem I added the duplicate id bug. My original problem was to use an draggable element without a styles (even members of bootstrap classes). See here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r4rp93ac/4/) So adding the styles helped me. The reason for the need of the style width and heigth is, that the droppable elements react to the center of the draggable entering their shape. So a bootstrap draggable with varying size is causing problems...

Answer (score 0):

`Id` should be unique, so if you wan two droppable zones, use `class` instead:

```
<div id="droppable2" class="droppable col-xs-3">
    <p>Drop
        <br>here</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable2" class="droppable col-xs-3">
    <p>Drop
        <br>here</p>
</div>
```

And

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find("p").html("Dropped!");
    }
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r4rp93ac/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also this wasn't actually my problem. I would have given up without your help.